# What's the profit margin for airlines between fuel cost per seat price per seat to the customer?

Tags: fuel, cost, airlines

I understand that there are other costs that go into the full price per seat, like maintenance, crew ect., but all I am asking about here is fuel.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details like airplane and location to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: This also varies a lot in time. The price of a barrel of crude oil has ranged from under $20 to over $140 over the last 20 years. Also you're asking for the profit margin (in the title) and then just the fuel cost (in the body).

Comment: Fuel price varies, seat price varies (in the same aircraft), some seats are not sold, engine efficiency varies. That's a lot of approximations to be done. In addition profit is determined by *all* costs, airlines are unlikely using a specific uplift on the fuel line of their cost cases.